# How we can find a word in JavaScript without HTML in a file.txt?

Tags: javascript, html

In my project I tried to find some words in a file, I coded the program in JS, but I have some syntax problem and I don't know why. The goal is when the program finds "rose" it writes on the terminal "flower" etc.
My program is :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

str.split(/\s+/).forEach(s =>
  console.log(
    s === 'rose'
      ? 'flower'
      : s === 'bird'
      ? 'animal'
      : s === 'cookie'
      ? 'dog'
      : 'unknown'
  )
);
```

The different errors which appear on the terminal are :

```
  js: "prog.js", line 5: syntax error
js: str.split(/\s+/).forEach(s =>
js: ............................^
js: "prog.js", line 6: syntax error
js:   console.log(
js: ..........^
js: "prog.js", line 7: syntax error
js:     s === 'rose'
js: ........^
js: "prog.js", line 9: syntax error
js:       : s === 'bird'
js: .......^
js: "prog.js", line 11: syntax error
js:       : s === 'cookie'
js: .......^
js: "prog.js", line 13: syntax error
js:       : 'unknown'
js: .......^
js: "prog.js", line 15: syntax error
js: );
js: ^
js: "prog.js", line 1: Compilation produced 7 syntax errors.
```

And to run the program I use this command : `rhino prog.js`

So can you help me to find the error please?

Comment: The Rhino version you're using doesn't support arrow functions; it's possible that *no* version of Rhino does. If you're doing JavaScript outside of browsers anything other than Node is probably a mistake (here in 2018).

Comment: @Pointy, ok I understand so what kind of solution you can propose please ?

Comment: @cpeUser2018 as Pointy already said, use Node instead of Rhino

Comment: Download the latest version of [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) and run your script using this command `node prog.js`.

Comment: What version of Rhino are you using? Look at this: https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html#ES2015-functions

Comment: I use this version > `v8.11.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because Rhino doesn't currently support arrow functions: ie `() => { ...}`

See: https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--parameters-defaults--arrow-function

You're in luck, this is an easy fix! Just remove the arrow function; this should work:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
  return console.log(s === 'rose' ? 'flower' : s === 'bird' ? 'animal' : s === 
'cookie' ? 'dog' : 'unknown');
});
```

Comment: I tried something like that but I have this error this with, and I don't understand why : `js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined.`

Comment: You need `require.js` in your project if you haven't already set it up.  More specifically, make sure you use `r.js` which is a modified version of `require.js` for Rhino.  

See: https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#rjs

Comment: think you so much for your help, I was able to solve the problem correctly